# What's the tense for remarking a thing happened in the past?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-tense, past-vs-present

Shall I change

> That Bilbo said he was a legendary burglar is really funny.

to

> That Bilbo said he was a legendary burglar was really funny.

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to change it for grammatical reasons. Both sentences are grammatically correct. You change it according to what you want the sentence to mean.

> That Bilbo said he was a legendary burglar is really funny.

This says that, at this moment, you think Bilbo's remark is funny.

> That Bilbo said he was a legendary burglar was really funny.

This says that, at some time in the past, you thought it was funny. Maybe you no longer think it is funny or maybe you do. We don't know what you think now. All we know from that statement is that you did think it was funny back then.